# Why is 301 Redirect Not Working After Removing .PHP Extension via HTACCESS?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, 301-redirect

I'm removing the `.php` extension from files contained within a specific directory on my website (`courses`) via `.htaccess` on Apache/2.2.26 (Unix).

Additionally, I'd like to 301 redirect the old `.php` version to non-php version.

Old URL Structure:

```
http://www.example.com/courses/blue-course.php
```

New URL Structure:

```
http://www.example.com/courses/blue-course
```

My Current Issues:

- non `.php` version of the pages are not 301 redirecting.
- both `.php` and non `.php` versions of the pages are viewable.

Here's my code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# External Routing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*\/courses\/)([^\s]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*courses\/)([^\s]+)\.php http://www.example.com/$1$2 [L,R=301]

# Internal Routing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than "not 301 redirecting" at all, I would expect your code to create a redirect loop. As the earlier redirect will also catch the rewritten URL (by the later directive) and redirect, etc. etc.

> non `.php` version of the pages are not 301 redirecting.

Isn't that correct? Or should the "non" or "not" be removed here?

> both `.php` and non `.php` versions of the pages are viewable.

That would seem to suggest that perhaps MultiViews is enabled. MultiViews needs to be disabled for your mod_rewrite directives to execute correctly. (You either use MultiViews *or* mod_rewrite here, however, you may have issues trying to *redirect* if MultiViews is enabled.) To ensure MultiViews is disabled, add the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

However, to avoid a redirect loop, instead of matching against `REQUEST_URI`, which changes as the URL is rewritten (the same as the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*), you should either match against `THE_REQUEST` (which holds the first line of the request and does not change) OR simply check that the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is empty to ensure you are only checking the initial request and not the rewritten request.

For example:

```
# External Routing
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*courses\/)([^\s]+)\.php http://www.example.com/$1$2 [L,R=301]
```

NB: Always *test* with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues.

However, your regex could be cleaned up a bit. According to your example URLs, `/courses` is the first path segment, however, your regex is matching "courses/" anywhere in the URL-path. And you are allowing any URL with path-info to be redirected - is that intentional? You only need a single backreference; not two. And there's no need to escape slashes in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. You don't necessarily need the scheme+hostname in the *substitution* string unless you have multiple domains?

So, this could perhaps be "simplified" to:

```
# External Routing
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(courses/[^\s]+)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

---

> ```
> # Internal Routing
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
> RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
> ```

This may work for the specific URLs you are testing, however, this rule can break easily (and it's not specifically targeting the `/courses` subdirectory). `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` is not necessarily the same as `%{REQUEST_URI}.php`. So, whilst the condition might succeed, you can still end up rewriting to an invalid URL, which could result in an endless loop - 500 Internal Server Error.

For example, given a request for `/courses/blue-course/foo` (based on your example), where `/courses` is a directory on the filesystem and `blue-course.php` is the file you intend to rewrite to (there is no subdirectory `/blue-course`) and `/foo` is just something that has been mistakenly added to the URL (perhaps even maliciously by an external third party), then this will result in a 500 error. Because `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` resolves to `<document-root>/courses/blue-course.php` (which exists) but `%{REQUEST_URI}.php` resolves to `/courses/blue-course/foo.php` (which does not exist). The rewriting process then starts over, resulting in an endless loop.

This can be resolved by adjusting the rule to something like:

```
# Internal Routing
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^courses/ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Assuming you don't have multiple file extensions, or dots in the file basename, eg. `blue-course.abc.php` then this can also be optimised by making sure that the requested URL does not already have a file extension (to avoid any static resources being tested). For example:

```
# Internal Routing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w{2,4}$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^courses/ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* negates its meaning.

#### In Summary

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# External Routing
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(courses/[^\s]+)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Internal Routing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w{2,4}$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

---

The directives above assume you are using the `.htaccess` file in the document root of your site. However, if you only need to target a specific directory and have minimal other mod_rewrite directives you need to inherit from parent configs then it can be beneficial to create an additional `.htaccess` file in that subdirectory to keep the config separate. However, the directives would need to be altered slightly:

```
RewriteEngine On

# External Routing
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^\s]+)\.php$ /courses/$1 [L,R=301]

# Internal Routing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w{2,4}$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Note that this would (by default) completely override any mod_rewrite directives in a parent config (*directory* context).

Comment: I sincerely appreciate you taking the time to submit such an informative (and correctly functioning) response. To clarify having a separate .htaccess file in the directory: Will it essentially override all rules in parent config that are applicable only to that specific directory?

Comment: With a separate `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory... By default, all the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file will be overridden (they will simply not execute) when a `/courses/<whatever>` URL is requested. However, other modules (such as mod_alias, `Redirect` or mod_setenvif, `SetEnvIf` or mod_expires, etc.) will execute as normal. Each Apache module works independently. By default, mod_rewrite directives are not inherited. There are ways to enable mod_rewrite inheritance (although on Apache 2.2 you are very limited in this respect), but this is not necessarily trivial.